# Protocol method not getting called in UIView

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have 2 UIViews
1st: ToolbarView:
This is the code for protocol in 1st view:

```
public enum ToolBarActionType: String {
  case style = "style"
  case undo = "undo"
  case redo = "redo"
}

public protocol ToolBarDelegate: AnyObject {
  func toolBarButtonAction(actionType: ToolBarActionType)
}

@objc public class ToolbarView: UIView {
 enum ToolbarItems: Int {
     case style = 1
    case undo = 2
    case redo = 3
  }

 public weak var delegate: ToolBarDelegate?

//This method is called onClick of toolbar buttons
@objc func toolBarButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let style = ToolbarItems(rawValue: sender.tag)
      switch style {
      case .style :
        delegate?.toolBarButtonAction(actionType: .insertionStyle)
      case .undo :
        delegate?.toolBarButtonAction(actionType: .undo)
      case .redo :
        delegate?.toolBarButtonAction(actionType: .redo)
      default :
        return
      }
    }
}
```

This is my 2nd view: TextView
This is the code in textview:

```
import Toolbar

 public class TextView: UIView, ToolBarDelegate {
 private var toolbar = Toolbar()

 public init() {
 toolbar.delegate = self
}

//this method is not getting called in TextView.
   public func toolBarButtonAction(actionType: ToolBarActionType) {
       switch actionType {
    
         case .style:
print("style is pressed")
          
       case .undo:
         print("style is pressed")
       case .redo:
         print("style is pressed")
       }
     }
}
```

Only the 1st views delegate method is called but not the 2nd views. Am I missing something here? Thank you!

Comment: I don’t think that init gets called. Check the documentation for [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ya init() doesn't get called. But where do I add this toolbar.delegate = self?

Comment: In one of the init methods that gets called, so override the one that is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate exists in `ToolbarView` where as you're initialising `Toolbar` object. Maybe try replacing

```
public class TextView: UIView, ToolBarDelegate {
    private var toolbar = ToolbarView()

    public init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        toolbar.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        toolbar.delegate = self
    }

    //this method is not getting called in TextView.
    public func toolBarButtonAction(actionType: ToolBarActionType) {
        switch actionType {
        case .style:
            print("style is pressed")
        case .undo:
            print("undo is pressed")
        case .redo:
            print("redo is pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that super.init() need to call so you can use delegate method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).